# XML Picture Change

Tags: java, android, xml, image, background

I want to change my xml code when i press a button. Is this possible?

So when i press the button i want that

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/steg"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">
```

changes into android:background="@drawable/test"

Thanks for the Help

JK

---

I tried your solutions but non worked :(

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class einstellungen extends Fragment {

    ImageButton btn;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.einstellungen, container, false);


        btn = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.boote);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.headerLayout)).setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.kapelle));
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

this is my class can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

try this `

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/steg"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">
```

`And in your class

```
((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.headerLayout)).setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

give an id to your layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/yourLayoutID"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
....
/>
```

then get the layout by

```
LinearLayout layout =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourLayoutID);
```

and after that you can set the background by using

```
layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test));
```